# how to use depdrop in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-basic-app

i want use A multi level dependent dropdown in yii2

this is my _from  :

```
 <?php $catList=ArrayHelper::map(app\models\NewsCat::find()->all(),'id','news_name');  ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'state_id')->dropDownList($catList, ['id'=>'cat_name', 'prompt'=>'Select category']);?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'city_id')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
            'options'=>['id'=>'sub_name'], 
            'pluginOptions'=>[
            'depends'=>['cat_name'],
            'placeholder'=>'Select subcategory',
            'url'=>  Url::to(['/opportunity/subcat'])
            ]
            ]);  ?>
```

and this is my controller :

```
 $out = [];
        if (isset($_POST['depdrop_parents']))
            {
            $parents = $_POST['depdrop_parents'];

            if ($parents != null)
                {
                $id = $parents[0];
                $out = \app\models\State::find()->all();


                echo Json::encode(['output' => $out, 'selected' => '1']);
                return;
                }
            }
        echo Json::encode(['output' => '', 'selected' => '']);
```

$out has data but i cant pass that data to form !

[image: $dropdown in yii2]

http://plugins.krajee.com/dependent-dropdown

Comment: add `use yii\helpers\Json;` or `use yii\web\Response;`. Your error says class json not found.

Comment: Yes, i agree with solution provided by Insane Skull.

Comment: Yes, the problem was solved